# Get specific custom field keys from a post and put into an array

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, array

I have the following code to look up the longitude and latitude based off of a custom field upon saving the post. My address fields (street_1, city and state) are separate. I have searched and thought that I could put the values from these separate meta keys into an array and pass them to the URL. I have the state value working but I need the whole address. I have tried many different ways and am now asking for help. Any clues will be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
function geocode_address($post_id)
{
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom();
    if(isset($custom_fields['state']) && !empty($custom_fields['state'][0]))
    {
 $resp = wp_remote_get( "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($custom_fields['state'][0])."&sensor=false" );
            if ( 200 == $resp['response']['code'] ) {
                    $body = $resp['body'];
                    $data = json_decode($body);
                    if($data->status=="OK"){
                            $latitude = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
                            $longitude = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
                            update_post_meta($post_id, "latitude", $latitude);
                            update_post_meta($post_id, "longitude", $longitude);
                    }
            }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'geocode_address');
```

Thank you,
Deon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to put them into an array.  According to [google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON) you should just separate out the various pieces of the address in the url like a standard (U.S.) formatted address.

```
// Example taken from google's docs:
$state = 'CA';
$street = 'Mountain View';
$address = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway';

function geocode_address($post_id)
{
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom();

    // just set $city, $state and $address to the appropriate custom field variables here

    if(isset($custom_fields['state']) && !empty($custom_fields['state'][0]))
    {

 $resp = wp_remote_get( "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($address . ',' . $city . ',' .$state)."&sensor=false" );
            if ( 200 == $resp['response']['code'] ) {
                    $body = $resp['body'];
                    $data = json_decode($body);
                    if($data->status=="OK"){
                            $latitude = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
                            $longitude = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
                            update_post_meta($post_id, "latitude", $latitude);
                            update_post_meta($post_id, "longitude", $longitude);
                    }
            }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'geocode_address');
```